# Error changing background color with dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and i just tried to change background color of an app bar but I am getting this error

```
9:13: Error: No named parameter with the name 'backgroundColor'.
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[900],
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Tried to change background color of app bar

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to really understand what you try to do and where you face an issue without a piece of code...

Does the following help?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[500],
          title: const Text('Neetadev APP'),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text('HOMEPAGE'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to change it for all your pages, you could also modify the Theme:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          color: Colors.purple[500],
        ),
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Neetadev APP')),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text('HOMEPAGE'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```